# Is it possible to intercept email sent button click event using office 365 javascript apps with office-js

Tags: office365-apps, office-js

Is it possible to intercept email sent button click event using office 365 javascript apps with office-js and is there any roadmap to know future feature sets of office-js ?

Answer (score 4):

No, it is not possible to intercept send nor has this functionality been announced for the future, but you can vote on it [on UserVoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/suggestions/10964871-add-itemsend-event-so-add-in-can-cancel-email)

Answer (score 0):

Now it is possible.
[Office Outlook events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/autolaunch?tabs=xmlmanifest)